# Ethernet connection to the device is automatically reset

Tags: ethernet

I'm accessing a ARM board from Linux via ethernet cable. The connection works.

For this, I use the following configuration

`macabeus@acer ~ $ sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up`

And then...

```
macabeus@acer ~ $ telnet 192.168.0.2
Trying 192.168.0.2...
Connected to 192.168.0.2.
Escape character is '^]'.


BusyBox v1.1.3 (2007.07.23-13:22+0000) Built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

/ #
```

For some reason, after a few seconds, Linux resets the connection and delete my configuration. I think he detects that he can not have Internet connection and kills the hope of getting though, I do not want it.

How to solve this problem?

I'm using Linux Mint.

Comment: Is there a `NetworkManager` or DHCP client daemon lurking anywhere?

Comment: @thrig Yes. `macabeus@acer ~ $ sudo NetworkManager` -> `O NetworkManager já está em execução (pid 994)`

Comment: Okay, what's the `NetworkManager` configuration set to do, especially for `eth0`? (Or do you need it?)

Comment: @thrig I used the following command, and returns nothing: `macabeus@acer /etc/NetworkManager $ sudo grep -r "eth0" .` That's how you search settings in NetworkManager? I have no experience.

Comment: What distribution is running on that board? Different distributions set up networking (including where NM looks for settings and how NM reacts when something else tries to manage the network) differently.

Comment: @Gilles Linux Mint